# Graph based weighting for sentence extraction in automatic summarization?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, summarization

I was reading a research paper [Automatic Text Document Summarization Based on
Machine Learning](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1h9VNiSABe5YjJSMGY5S3JaUmx1RlVwQk9kdDhGS0VRYVBR/view?usp=sharing) and under the  Table 1 corresponding to graph based weighting, they  have used a feature F1 called Aggregate Similarity.

I have tried searching the web , though i have found mentions of things like "Flexible aggregate similarity" but 'm not sure how does it relate to the task of automatic summarization and weighing sentences.

What exactly is meant by aggregate similarity and  How is it calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate Similarity is the summation of similarities for each node (aggregate similarity).This similarity is simply a vocabulary  overlap between the 2 nodes (2 sentences) under consideration divided by the longest length of the 2 sen-
tences (for normalization).

Aggregate similarity measures the importance of a sentence.

Instead of counting the number of links connecting a node (sentence) to other nodes (Bushy path), aggregate similarity sums the weights (similarities) on the links.